# How To Get Datatables Column's Value?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, datatables

I want to get Datatables column's value. Here is my datatables script:

```
$(function () {
        $('#kategoriTable').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": true,
            "scrollX": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url" : "kugi/getDataKategori",
                "dataSrc" : function(json) {
                    console.log(json);
                    return json.ProposalCategories
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CategoryId"}, // I want to get this value, and then use it to edit the data
                { "data": "Name"},
                { "data": "Code"},
                { "data": "TypeName"},
                { "data": "IsAbstract"},
                { "data": "DefSrcOrganisationName"},
                { "data": null,
                  "bSortable": false,
                  "mRender": function (o) { return '<a href="kugi/edit_usulan_kategori/"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Edit</button></a>'; }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

After that I want to send this value to this code

```
return '<a href="kugi/edit_usulan_kategori/XXXX"><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Edit</button></a>'
```

How can I get the value of `CategoryId` then put it to `XXXX` ?

Thanks before.

Comment: That plugin has [extensive documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().data()) try searching there before asking a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close - you actually have access to all column values through the `row` param :

```
columns: [
   { data: "CategoryId" }, 
   { data: "Name" },
   { data: "Code" },
   { data: "TypeName" },
   { data: "IsAbstract" },
   { data: "DefSrcOrganisationName" },
   { data: null,
     sortable: false,
     render: function(data, type, row) {
         return '<a href="kugi/edit_usulan_kategori/'+row.CategoryId+'">'+
                '<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Edit</button></a>'
     }
   }      
]
```

documentation here -> **https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render**

Comment: That code helped me a lot. Accepted answer @davidkonrad